# MongoDB Atlas Search - slow count of matched documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have a collection with 11M records, which contains among other properties, a "Name" property with a client name:

```
{
    "Name" : "Teressa Bella"
}
```

I have created an Atlas Search index on the "Name" field with the following definition:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "Name": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My use case counting all the documents that match a certain term which I'm doing like so:

```
db.getCollection('recipients').aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      "text": {
        "query": "Teressa",
        "path": "Name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "total"
  }
])
```

The problem is that this query takes about 40s to complete on an M30 Atlas cluster (sometimes 10s or 20s if entirely fetched from memory, I presume).
Is this within the expected execution time for matching a term on 11M documents?
I would appreciate any suggestions on how i can optimize this kind of query.

Comment: What was the value returned of `$count`?

Comment: About 80k records

Comment: @djed did you find a solution for your problem.

Comment: @BathriNathan no I didn't, however I didn't pursue the issue much further since then.

Comment: @djed thanks for sharing this. hope we will get a solution for this soon.